# Unable to Load Assembly in Worker Service (.Net Core3.1 and NLog 4.9.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget-package, asp.net-core-3.1, nlog

This is a repeated question but don't know what happens in this solution  scenario , We are setting up an `WorkerService` in `.Net core 3.1`. For logging  we are using `NLog`. While building we were getting the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

This error occues in Project.cs(shown in code below). The ServiceFileLogger belongs to another Library Class.(folder struncture is shown below)

[image]

[image]

**Project.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseWindowsService()

                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;

                    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
                    services.AddSingleton<ServiceSettings>(config.GetSection("Application").Get<ServiceSettings>());
// Error comes here during the injection.                    
services.AddTransient<ServiceFileLogger>(_logger=> new ServiceFileLogger("DATASOURCEMONITOR", config.GetSection("Application:LogLevel").ToString()));

                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
}
```

We even changed the `Nlog version 4.9.2` to `NLog version 4.9.0` ()
**More Info**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-WorkerServiceLearn-817A165A-A227-4F73-ABBC-EE79E10DE8A3</UserSecretsId>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="WorkerServiceLearn.Library">
      <HintPath>..\WorkerServiceLearn.Library\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WorkerServiceLearn.Library.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Don't know what to change here, kindly help us and provide some documents to validate.

Repository Link is here, kindly go through it and advice us.

Comment: have you added package for NLog? I cannot see in the project file

Comment: @viveknuna already added check image 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install NLog  also by using the Nuget Package Manager or running the below command in the package manager console.

```
Install-Package NLog -Version 4.7.2
```

Reference: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#1-add-dependency-in-csproj-manually-or-using-nuget

Comment: not avail.. is it write code like this?                                                           
ServiceFileLogger fileLogger = new ServiceFileLogger("DATASOURCEMONITOR", appSettings.LogLevel.ToString());

Comment: please make sure that you have followed all the step mentioned here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Comment: How did you solve the issue finally? What was the issue?

Comment: Library file .cs project Nlog version was 4.4.12 , but i installed 4.9.2. Created another folder 'packages' which  is added along with these two projects. Now its 4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

NLog works for me like this:

In the **WorkerServiceLearn** project:

- Add Nuget package : Nlog
- Add Nuget package : NLog.Extensions.Logging
- Add a "nlog.config" file
- Declare NLog service in the code:

  ```
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                var config = hostContext.Configuration;

                services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                {
                    // Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                    loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Debug);

                    // NLog.Extensions.Logging
                    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
                });
  ```

In the **WorkerServiceLearnLibrary** project:

- Remove NLog.Web.AspNetCore (I personally don't use it)
- Add Nuget package : NLog